# How can I edit a file posted by Multer with the excel.js library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, express, multer

I am working on a project that assesses a spreadsheet then makes edits to it but my edits are not saving. I used multer to save the CSV to 'uploads/HVACresultfile.csv" but I cannot seem to edit it and write it properly with the excel.js NPM library. what am I missing?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
var Excel = require('exceljs');
const index = require("../routes/index")
console.log('hvac doctor loads')

function readFile () {
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
var resultFile = workbook.csv.readFile('uploads/HVACresultfile.csv')
var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('uploads/HVACresultfile.csv')
.then(function(resultFile) {
        resultFile.modified = new Date();
        worksheet.getCell('A9').border = {
            top: {style:'double', color: {argb:'FF00FF00'}},
            left: {style:'double', color: {argb:'FF00FF00'}},
            bottom: {style:'double', color: {argb:'FF00FF00'}},
            right: {style:'double', color: {argb:'FF00FF00'}}
        };
        console.log('reads')
        writeFile()
    })};

function writeFile (workbook) {
    var workbook = createAndFillWorkbook('uploads/HVACresultfile.csv');
    workbook.xlsx.writeFile('wutwut')
        .then(function() {
            console.log('written as xlsx')
        });
    }


readFile()
```

Edit: Here is the specific error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at readFile (***/***/hvacdoctor/controllers/hvacdoctor.js:12:5)
```

The specific error is cannot read property then of undefined. but haven't I defined everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the writeFile function you have initialised workbook with a function, not provided in the example. Please pass the workbook you have created in readFile function as parameter to writeFile.

```
    function readFile () {
       /*
           workbook editing done here
        */
        writeFile(workbook)
    })};

    function writeFile (workbook) {
        workbook.xlsx.writeFile('wutwut')
        .then(function() {
            console.log('written as xlsx')
        });
    }

   readFile()
```

*PS:  **then** is used at two places in your example. Please make clear on which function, the error occurs. Since I am not having enough reputation to comment, instead of asking for clarity in comment, I am posting this answer with an assumption that the error is in writefile function.

Comment: I think I should pass my uploaded file as a parameter to my read file function and define it outside the function